# Action of CommandButton doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a **ToolBar** which contain a number of button. these button must be a link to other xhtml pages. But they don't work. This is my code :

```
         <h:form>
            <p:toolbar>  
                <p:toolbarGroup align="left">  
                    <p:commandButton id="btn1" type="button" action="faces/Genseignant" value="Gestion Enseignants" icon="ui-icon-folder-open" />  

                    <p:commandButton id="btn2" type="button" action="Gclasse" value="Gestion Classes" icon="ui-icon-folder-open" />  

                    <p:commandButton id="btn3" type="button" action="Getudiant" value="Gestion Etudiants" icon="ui-icon-folder-open" />

                    <p:commandButton id="btn4" type="button" action="Gmatiere" value="Gestion Matières" icon="ui-icon-folder-open" />

                    <p:commandButton id="btn5" type="button" action="Gsalle" value="Gestion Salles" icon="ui-icon-folder-open" />

                    <p:commandButton id="btn6" type="button" value="Gestion Horaires" icon="ui-icon-folder-open" />

                    <p:separator />  

                </p:toolbarGroup>  

                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">  
                    <p:menuButton value="Options">  
                        <p:menuitem value="Acceuil" action="Genseignant"/>  
                        <p:menuitem value="Déconnectté(e)" />  
                    </p:menuButton>  
                </p:toolbarGroup>  

            </p:toolbar>
        </h:form>
```

When I try this with a MenuBar, It works properly.
Any suggetions please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `type="button"` attribute. Otherwise commandButtons cannot be used this way.

The difference is evident from the browser source:

This is the button **with** `type="button"`:

```
<button id="myform:btn1" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

This is the button **without** `type="button"` which defaults to `type="submit"`:

```
<button id="myform:btn1"   
        onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'myform',source:'myform:btn1',
                                process:'@all'}); return false;" 
        type="submit" role="button" 
        aria-disabled="false">
```

Comment: Good to hear that it works. Please don't forget to mark my answer as "accepted" if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: @ Matt Handy, Please when I click on 'Acceuil' button , It navigate to index page , but index page changes size. How resolve this.

Comment: What does it mean "changes size"? What exactly changes?

Comment: The index xhtml page is bigger, All buttons are biggers

Comment: Might be a css problem. But this seems to be a different problem. Please create a new question and put the index.xhtml source in it.